# How do I filter and merge the two array in react

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a data `data`, `room` and `teacher`.

```
data = [{
 id: null,
 name: 'edward',
 room: 'emerald'
}]

room = [{
 id: 1,
 name: 'emerald'
},{
 id: 2,
 name: 'diamond'
}]

teacher = [{
 id: 1,
 name: 'james'
},{
 id: 2,
 name: 'edward'
}]
```

and what I want is to change the `data` value of `id` to teacher `id` then the room value change to `room id`. which it would be like this.

```
data = [{
 id: 2,
 room: 1
}]
```

What I did is to the flatmap and filter but it doesn't display anything

```
data.flatMap(x =>room.filter(room => room.code === x).map(y => { return { id: null, room: y.id } }));
```

Comment: _"it doesn't display anything"_... none of the code you have displays anything. For that you would need something like `console.log()`, `document.write()`, etc

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is create [maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) indexing the `room` and `teacher` entries by their names.

Then you can map the `data` array to lookup the relevant IDs

```js
const data = [{id:null,name:'edward',room:'emerald'}]
const room = [{id:1,name:'emerald'},{id:2,name:'diamond'}]
const teacher = [{id:1,name:'james'},{id:2,name:'edward'}]

// Creates a Map with entries keyed by the given property
const indexByProp = (arr, prop = "name") =>
  arr.reduce((map, entry) => map.set(entry[prop], entry), new Map())

const roomsByName = indexByProp(room)
const teachersByName = indexByProp(teacher)

const newData = data.map(d => ({
  id: teachersByName.get(d.name)?.id, // use optional chaining
  room: roomsByName.get(d.room)?.id   // in case the lookup fails
}))

console.log(newData)
```

---

Because your question is tagged with [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript), the appropriate declaration for `indexByProp` is

```js
function indexByProp<T>(arr: T[], prop: keyof T = "name" as keyof T) {
  return arr.reduce((map, entry) => map.set(entry[prop], entry), new Map())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way :

```
const nameId = [...room, ...teacher].find(el => el.name === data[0].name).id;
const roomId = [...room, ...teacher].find(el => el.name === data[0].room).id;

const dat = [{id: nameId, room: roomId}]

console.log(dat);
```

If the number of entries in your initial data array was larger, I would write a function to return `nameId` and `roomId` and additional `Ids`.

As follows :

```
function finder(idToFind){
  return [...room, ...teacher].find(el => el.name === data[0][idToFind]).id;
}

const dat = [{id: finder('name'), room: finder('room')}];

console.log(dat);
```